# Mobile Version CSS

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm pretty sure it's going to be something stupid, but I'm not being able to find the issue myself.

Does anyone knows why my website mobile version looks like this
[My mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhyLE.png)

Instead of this...
[How it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUPy1.png)

Your help is very much appreciated =)

```css
#mobile {
    display: none;
}

#desktop {
    display: inline;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        background-image: none;
    }
    #wrapper {
        width: auto;
        min-width: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    header {
        border-bottom: 5px solid #fef6c2;
    }
    h1 {
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        padding-top: 1em;
        padding-bottom: 1em;
        font-size: 2.5em;
    }
    nav {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        padding-top: 0px;
        margin: 10px;
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }
    nav li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    nav a {
        padding: 1em;
        width: 5em;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-style: none;
    }
    nav ul,
    #heroroad,
    #heromugs,
    #heroguitar {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    main {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        font-size: 90%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    header {
        background-image: url(images/javajammini.jpg);
        height: 128px;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
        text-align: center;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
    nav {
        margin: 0px;
    }
    nav a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0.2em;
        width: auto;
        border-bottom: 1px #fef6c2;
    }
    nav li {
        display: block;
    }
    main {
        padding-top: 1px;
    }
    h2 {
        padding: 0.5em 0em 0em 0.5em;
        margin-right: 0.5em;
    }
    .details {
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
    }
    #heroroad,
    #heromugs,
    #heroguitar {
        background-image: none;
        height: auto;
    }
    .floatleft {
        padding-left: 0.5em;
        padding-right: 0.5em;
    }
    #mobile {
        display: inline;
    }
    #desktop {
        display: none;
    }
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header,
nav,
main,
footer {
    display: block;
}

body {
    background-color: #FCEBB6;
    color: #221811;
    font-family: Arial;
    background-image: url(images/background.gif);
}

header {
    background-color: #D2B48C;
    height: 150px;
    background-image: url(images/javajamlogo.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

nav {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    float: left;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 200px;
}

nav a:link {
    color: #FEF6C2;
}

nav a:visited {
    color: #D2B48C;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #CC9933;
}

nav ul {
    padding-left: 3em;
    list-style: none;
}

main {
    padding: 0em 0em 2em 0em;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 200px;
    background-color: #FEF6C2;
}

main h2,
main h3,
main h4,
main p,
main div,
main ul,
main dl {
    padding: 0em 2em 0em 3em;
}

footer {
    background-color: #D2B48C;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: .60em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #221811;
    border-top: 2px solid #221811;
}

#wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #231814;
    min-width: 900px;
    max-width: 1280px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}

h1 {
    padding-top: 45px;
    padding-left: 220px;
    font-size: 3em;
}

h4 {
    background-color: #d2b48c;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: solid 2px black;
    padding-bottom: 0em;
    clear: left;
}

.details {
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%;
    overflow: auto;
}

img {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#heroroad {
    background-image: url(images/heroroad.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}

#heromugs {
    background-image: url(images/heromugs.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}

#heroguitar {
    background-image: url(images/heroguitar.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}

.floatleft {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>JavaJam Coffee House</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="javajam.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- [if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1>JavaJam Coffee House</h1>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
                    <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <main>
            <div id="heroroad"></div>
            <h2>Follow the Winding Road to JavaJam</h2>
            <p>We're a little out of the way, but take a drive down Route 42 to JavaJam today! Indulge in our locally rosted free-trade coffee and home-made pastries. You'll feel rigth at home at JavaJam!</p>
            <h3>JavaJam Coffee House features</h3>

            <ul>
                <li>Specialty Coffee and Tea</li>
                <li>Bagels, Muffins, and Organic Snacks</li>
                <li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
                <li>Open Mic Night</li>
            </ul>
            <p>12312 Main Street<br>Mountain Home, CA 93923<br><a id="mobile" href="tel:1-888-555-5555">1-888-555-5555</a> <span id="desktop">1-888-555-5555</span> </p>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <p>JavaJam Copyright &copy; 2013 Coffee House<br><a href="name@email.com">name@email.com</a></p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your (@media) blocks bottom of whole css.

Try this...

```css
#mobile {
    display: none;
}

#desktop {
    display: inline;
}



* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header,
nav,
main,
footer {
    display: block;
}

body {
    background-color: #FCEBB6;
    color: #221811;
    font-family: Arial;
    background-image: url(images/background.gif);
}

header {
    background-color: #D2B48C;
    height: 150px;
    background-image: url(images/javajamlogo.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

nav {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    float: left;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 200px;
}

nav a:link {
    color: #FEF6C2;
}

nav a:visited {
    color: #D2B48C;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #CC9933;
}

nav ul {
    padding-left: 3em;
    list-style: none;
}

main {
    padding: 0em 0em 2em 0em;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 200px;
    background-color: #FEF6C2;
}

main h2,
main h3,
main h4,
main p,
main div,
main ul,
main dl {
    padding: 0em 2em 0em 3em;
}

footer {
    background-color: #D2B48C;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: .60em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #221811;
    border-top: 2px solid #221811;
}

#wrapper {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
    background-color: #231814;
    min-width: 900px;
    max-width: 1280px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}

h1 {
    padding-top: 45px;
    padding-left: 220px;
    font-size: 3em;
}

h4 {
    background-color: #d2b48c;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: solid 2px black;
    padding-bottom: 0em;
    clear: left;
}

.details {
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%;
    overflow: auto;
}

img {
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#heroroad {
    background-image: url(images/heroroad.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}

#heromugs {
    background-image: url(images/heromugs.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}

#heroguitar {
    background-image: url(images/heroguitar.jpg);
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 250px;
}

.floatleft {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        background-image: none;
    }
    #wrapper {
        width: auto;
        min-width: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    header {
        border-bottom: 5px solid #fef6c2;
    }
    h1 {
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        padding-top: 1em;
        padding-bottom: 1em;
        font-size: 2.5em;
    }
    nav {
        float: none;
        width: auto;
        padding-top: 0px;
        margin: 10px;
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }
    nav li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    nav a {
        padding: 1em;
        width: 5em;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-style: none;
    }
    nav ul,
    #heroroad,
    #heromugs,
    #heroguitar {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
    main {
        padding: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        font-size: 90%;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    header {
        background-image: url(images/javajammini.jpg);
        height: 128px;
    }
    h1 {
        font-size: 2em;
        text-align: center;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
    nav {
        margin: 0px;
    }
    nav a {
        display: block;
        padding: 0.2em;
        width: auto;
        border-bottom: 1px #fef6c2;
    }
    nav li {
        display: block;
    }
    main {
        padding-top: 1px;
    }
    h2 {
        padding: 0.5em 0em 0em 0.5em;
        margin-right: 0.5em;
    }
    .details {
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
    }
    #heroroad,
    #heromugs,
    #heroguitar {
        background-image: none;
        height: auto;
    }
    .floatleft {
        padding-left: 0.5em;
        padding-right: 0.5em;
    }
    #mobile {
        display: inline;
    }
    #desktop {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>JavaJam Coffee House</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="javajam.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- [if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1>JavaJam Coffee House</h1>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                    <li><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
                    <li><a href="jobs.html">Jobs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <main>
            <div id="heroroad"></div>
            <h2>Follow the Winding Road to JavaJam</h2>
            <p>We're a little out of the way, but take a drive down Route 42 to JavaJam today! Indulge in our locally rosted free-trade coffee and home-made pastries. You'll feel rigth at home at JavaJam!</p>
            <h3>JavaJam Coffee House features</h3>

            <ul>
                <li>Specialty Coffee and Tea</li>
                <li>Bagels, Muffins, and Organic Snacks</li>
                <li>Music and Poetry Readings</li>
                <li>Open Mic Night</li>
            </ul>
            <p>12312 Main Street<br>Mountain Home, CA 93923<br><a id="mobile" href="tel:1-888-555-5555">1-888-555-5555</a> <span id="desktop">1-888-555-5555</span> </p>
        </main>
        <footer>
            <p>JavaJam Copyright &copy; 2013 Coffee House<br><a href="name@email.com">name@email.com</a></p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put both of your media queries at the bottom of your CSS code.

Put CSS code for @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px)

and then put CSS code for @media only screen and (max-width: 768px)

**Order is important in CSS.**